# Find directory and sub-directory permissions from a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-permissions

How do I find the permissions of folder and sub folder using a batch script?

Here's what I used; it provides the output for 1 folder only and not its subfolder:

```
@echo off
set target=C:\test
cacls "%target%" > c:\list.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%* in ('dir /b /ad "%Target%"') do cacls "%target%%%*"
```

Comment: Are you missing a backslash? Is your `For` loops' `Do` command supposed to output to `C:\list.txt` too?

Comment: Don't use `%%*` as `for` variables, use letters, as such characters look really confusing...

Comment: Add `/s` to the `dir` command to process sub-directories.